# How to auto-login as root on Debian 11 with LightDM and Xfce?

Tags: debian, login, xfce, root

I'm doing some testing which requires a lot of rebooting. It's a throwaway VM off the Internet. I'm using the Xfce desktop environment and want it to auto-login `root` user.

But adding the autologin stuff to the `lightdm.conf` setting it to `root` and adding root to the autologin group doesn't seem to be enough. I still get the password dialog when rebooting the VM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
[daemon]
# ...

# Enabling automatic login
AutomaticLoginEnable = true
AutomaticLogin = root
```

Then comment this line

```
#auth   required    pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
```

in `/etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin`:

```
sudo sed -e '/pam_succeed_if.so/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin
```

Archlinux wiki:

- [Enabling autologin](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM#Enabling_autologin)
- [Enabling interactive passwordless login](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM#Enabling_interactive_passwordless_login)

Comment: This works perfectly.  The test VM boots into desktop as root at start.